# Cannot boot Ubuntu 18.04 in default Ubuntu enviroment

Tags: boot, 18.04, desktop-environments

I have a HP-notebook with Dual booted Windows, and I'm experiencing this problem from quiet a few days, **after I type in my password at the login screen**, Ubuntu gets stuck at a pink screen with only my mouse cursor visible, there is no sort of error shown at all

**Booting from any other desktop environment works** and starts in seconds as expected, however I prefer the default Ubuntu environment. I want to know what is the problem here and how do I solve it.

This is a picture I took of the tty system log running `less /var/log/syslog` when my systems got stuck recently if it helps:

[image: tty screenshot]

Comment: If I experienced this, I would log in to a tty and inspect the system logs for errors.

Comment: @OrganicMarble How do I Login to a tty and inspect the system logs for errors?

Comment: When your system gets stuck, press ctrl-alt-f2 to get a tty, then log in. The logs are in /var/log, start with syslog.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've added the syslog output as you suggested, does the Error -2 mean I have no more disk space left? Because there is still a lot of empty disk space left for my Ubuntu root